# Cannot access firebase storage with cloudways server. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cors, cloudways

[Thats the error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H40c.png)

How can access that data without getting blocked by cors in server cloudways? Im using react.js

Comment: put your dev environment on the allow list.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a little proxy for your react application that is used in your **dev environment**.

For this, you can simply use the package `http-proxy-middleware`:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware

After installation, you need to create a file, e.g. "setupProxy.js" in your
`/src` directory with the according settings. Something like this can work:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(
    '/storage',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '/storage': '/',
      },
    })
  );
};
```

In you app, you then need not to call `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/whateverpath`, but your proxy: `/storage/whateverpath`.